# Passing additional data to a template in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Every time I code something using Django, I am faced to the same issue (I think this is due to my lack of experience using this framework):

I know how to pass arguments I had from a queryset to a template and how to display it but I don't know how to add argument computed in the view and use them in the template.

**Simple View (I master it) :**
*Example: Retrieve a list of Pizzas and display them in a template*

**views.py**

```
Pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()
return render_to_response( "pizza.html" , {'pizzas':Pizzas} )
```

**pizza.html**

```
{% for pizza in pizzas %}
    <li>pizza.name</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But, let's say I want to add some arguments linked to the queryset but which are not in the database like something I computed in the view, I don't know how to pass this argument to the template and how to use it -> **EDIT : I want to order all my pizza by total calories in the template.**

*Example : For each Pizzas, I have computed the number of calories*

**views.py**

```
Pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()
tab = []
for pizza in Pizzas:
    # Compute some data and return the total number of calories for one pizza
    total_number_calories = XXX
    tab.append({'p':pizza,'calories':total_number_calories'})        
return render_to_response( "pizza.html" , {'pizzas_calories':tab} )
```

**pizza.html**

```
?
```

I am not even sure my way to pass these additional data to the template is good (creating a table and pass it as an argument to the template.

If you have any idea or best practices to do that in Django I'll take it (and lot of people using Django will do the same !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always try and do as much as possible in the view. With the code you've shown, ordering by total calories is just one extra line after the for loop:

```
tab.sort(key=lambda t: t['calories'])
```

Comment: Wow !! Great This is perfect ! It is pure python right ? How can I sort in decreasing order (this solution is in increasing number) ?

Comment: EDIT: I find it : tab.sort(key=lambda t: t['calories'], reverse= True)

Answer (score 0):

From your view to the template is a one way street; this means that without doing a request back to your view, there is no way to "send data back".

However, while you are in the template you can manipulate objects easily; and this is done using [custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Your template can pass any object that it got from the view to your own filter, and the result of the filter is shown back in the template.

In your case, you can write a filter called `caloriecount`, with the same logic you would use in the view:

```
@register.filter
def caloriecount(obj): # Only one argument.
    # compute calorie for pizza object
    # total_calories = 
    return total_calories
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for pizza in pizzas %} 
   {{ pizza|caloriecount }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yep I thought to do that but I forgot to mention one thing: I want to order my Pizzas by total calories ! Is it possible to do this with template tags ?
If I compute all my calories in the view and send the pizzas with the total calories count to the template in one short, do you think it is possible ?

Comment: You should do ordering in the view, and such little details should be part of your question.